# how to bind click event with existing function in angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a code

```
$('#formSubmit').click(function() { alert("Hi"); // and some long code };
```

This works fine on clicking formSubmit button. 
now say I want to create a seperate function and then bind it with formSubmit button

```
$scope.check = function(){ alert("Hi");  //some long code };
```

and try to bind it using

```
$('#formSubmit').click($scope.check());
```

it doesn't work.
Please suggest me on how to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#formSubmit').click(function() { $scope.check(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-click`    :

```
<input type="button" ng-click="check()">
```